# djstripe (django stripe) - should I create local or remote customers first?

Tags: django, stripe-payments

When I receive my stripe token after a valid form: what data should I be using to create my local customer model? Many fields returned from the stripe create customer JSON response are incompatible with the local dj.stripe Customer model.

Am I supposed to be deleting and changing fields from the stripe JSON response to shoehorn it into my local model or am I missing the advantage of using djstripe?

Answer (score 0):

If you are using the djstripe Customer object, you should use the built in function `Customer.create(subscriber=user)` instead of the regular `Customer.objects.create(x,y,z)`.

The docs are incomplete as of writing, but see the [djstripe github page](https://github.com/dj-stripe/dj-stripe) for more info.